# How to solve a git merge conflict resulting in a corrupt project

Tags: xcode, git-merge-conflict

Some time ago I created two branches from the master without commiting the build version first. So now when I tried to merge one of the branches into my master I couldn't. I checked out the master and saw that it's corrupt now. I tried to resolve the problem manually with the project.pbxproj but that didn't help. Then I tried to overwrite the master with the one branch and now the branch is also corrupt. I don't now how to fix it, please help.

This is what it looks like right now, I can't see my files or anything.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "corrupt"? What problem exactly are you facing?

Comment: @gcharita I've added an image to the original post - it is corrupt in so far that Xcode can not open the files - "The file couldn't be opened".

Comment: Is there any conflicts in project.pbxproj that are not fixed yet?

Comment: Everything is still in git, so just `git reset --hard` back to a commit _before_ you started making all these mistakes. That's the entire purpose of git! OK, not the _entire_ purpose, but it's an important purpose: you have the power of "undo".

Comment: Maybe your .proj file is corrupted and that’s why the file tree cannot be loaded. Fixing the conflict there and rebooting Xcode should solve the issue

Comment: @gcharita Thanks, I fixed the project.pbxproj on the branch and it's back (I'm relieved). Unfortunately the same fix didn't work on the master. Any ideas?

Comment: @Anna are you facing the same issue in master branch? (the one that shown in image)

Comment: @gcharita Yes, exactly the same

Comment: @matt `git reset --hard` was helpful, I could fix the project.pbxproj so the branch is working again but the master is still corrupt (same as seen in the image above). The same fix doesn't work at master.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the same fix doesn't work at master". Sure it does. Get onto master and reset it to before you made these mistakes. By the way, note that you will need to close the project and reopen it using the workspace file. Changes in the project are not reflected while it is open.